# Django Reversion - How to use With Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-reversion

I'm trying to use ***Django Reversion*** with my ***django-rest***, but i still confuse about it or i just couldn't what i want in `Document`.

**`Here what i tried`**

**`Settings`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'reversion'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware'
]
```

**`In Model`**

```
@reversion.register()
class History(models.Model):
    pass
```

**`In ModelViewset`**

```
from reversion.views import RevisionMixin

class HistoryViewset(RevisionMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = History.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HistorySerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    # if pagination page = none, it will return all page

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        if 'page' in request.query_params:
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            if page is not None:
                serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
                return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then i try to update `My Model` and try to `GET` request from *api endpoint*, i got ***null*** Value.

What do i ***Missing***???

I'll appreciate of all ur Help. Thanks...

Comment: What's "My Django Rest"? How is updating model relevant in this question? where do you get `null` value?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko "My Django Rest", sorry i mean **django rest**. I updated in **User Model**, and get **empty** Array from ***localhost:8000/api/v1/history***

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Or do i need to **register Model directly** like this *`reversion.register(model, **options)`*